# DXT3 (BC2) compression format alpha data

Tags: c++, dds-format, dxt

I'm trying to read image info from a dds file. I managed to get the DXT1 and DXT5 formats working fine, however I have a question concerning the alpha data of the DXT3 format (Also know as [BC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression#DXT2_and_DXT3)).
When looking at the layout of a compressed [BC2 block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb694531(v=vs.85).aspx#BC2), it shows the alpha data for the 16-pixel block is stored in the first 8 bytes of the data, with each value taking up 4 bits.

Does this mean that, since the stored alpha value can only be 0-15, the actual alpha data is calculated as follows:

```
unsigned char bitvalue = GetAlphaBitValue(); // assume this works and gets the 4-bit value i am looking for
unsigned char alpha = (bitvalue / 15.0f) * 255;
```

Is this correct, or am I looking at it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [this specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_compression_s3tc.txt) seems to say:

> The alpha component for a texel at location (x,y) in the block is
>           given by alpha(x,y) / 15.

Because the result there is supposed to be in [0 .. 1], not [0 .. 255].

Since 255 is divisible by 15, it's probably easier to think of the transformation to [0 .. 255] as

```
uint8_t alpha = bitvalue * 17;
```

It is now more obvious that what's going on is the usual "replicate" mapping (just like eg CSS short color codes) that gives a nice spreading of output values (allows both the minimum and the maximum values to be encoded, and has equal steps between all values).